# How to store page url to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, url

I know this may sound novice to some of the members of this board. I'm attempting to create a 'bookmarking' feature. Is there a way to store page urls to mysql through php? For example, the browser has a save button and when pressed the url a person is viewing is stored in mysql.

I've attempted to do this and its gone very horrible to say the least. I would greatly appreciate any feedback.

```
   <html>
   <body>
   <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] ?>" method="post">
   <input type="submit" value="Save" />
   </form>
   </body>
   </html>

   <?php
   $url = $_GET['url'];

   $dbc = mysqli_connect('xxxx', 'xxxx', 'xxxx', 'xxxx')

  or die('Error connecting to MySQL server'); 

  $query = "INSERT INTO xxxx (url)".

  "VALUES('$url')"; 

  $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)

 or die('Error.');
 mysqli_close($dbc);
 ?>
```

Comment: attach your attempt regardless how bad it is

Comment: you should you $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] not $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] for more see http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 1):

this is the index page for example

```
  <?php
    function curPageURL() {
     $pageURL = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
 $pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
 return $pageURL;
}
?>
<html>
<body>
<form action="storeBookmark.php?url=<?php echo curPageURL();" method="GET">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

in storeBookmark.php

```
<?php 
$url = $_GET['url'];
.........
?>
```

and then make the insert statement to your database ***note: this solution i wrote just to show u a very simple way to do that***

Comment: sorry, i tried to post my code but it says i cant answer my own question until 7 hours. i'm going to try to use the example above for now.

Comment: no man edit the question above their is an edit button under your question